# Tomcat Server fails when startup in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Getting below exception while executing startup.sh for Tomcat. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I'm using RedHat Linux, tomcat version is 6.0.26

When I use java simply I face the same exception.

I set the JAVA_HOME and path varaible in /etc/profile as

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_30  
export JAVA_HOME  

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH  
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this [blog](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) 
This is probably java configuration issue.

Make sure JAVA_HOME is setup correctly

Can you post output of this command?

```
 java -version
```

Are you able to run any other java app? Or problem just with tomcat?

Comment: Actually my downloaded jdk has some issues. Resolved by extracting the bin using linux command